# Maths library for Java

Tags: java, math

What is the best library for Java to do numeric stuff like calculating integrals, finding roots of a function, calculating different probability cdf's, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, [Apache's Math](http://commons.apache.org/math/) library provides variety of functions you need for. Check it out. May be, its useful for you,

Comment: I had a look, but sadly it doesn't contain Gauss-Kronrod integration implementation, so its rather useless :( I actually moved to C++ and use GSL, which is a shame really.